# Django list of timestamps from DateTimeFields in output of group-by

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a model that looks like the following (some irrelevant fields have been omitted):

```
class Note(models.Model):
    enterprise_id = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    field_id = models.IntegerField()
    activity = models.TextField(choices=ACTIVITY_CHOICES)
    user_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I would like to (in SQL terms) group by the combination of (enterprise_id, field_id, activity, year of user_date) and then for each group, list the user_dates from Notes that went into it.  The following queryset works, but the array_agg list ends up being a string such as `[datetime.datetime(2017,1,1,0,0,0),...]` or similar, which is not very easily parsable.

Is there a way that I can `ArrayAgg` the unix timestamp from the `user_date` field, rather than the datetime object itself? Or failing that, `ArrayAgg` the tuple of (year, month, day) so it can be parsed?

```
qs = self.get_queryset()\
            .annotate(year=ExtractYear('user_date'))\
            .values('activity', 'enterprise_id', 'field_id', 'year')\
            .order_by('activity', 'enterprise_id', 'field_id', 'year') \
            .annotate(dates=ArrayAgg('user_date'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get a list of datetime objects, you can use a map to parse it.

```
dates = list(map(lambda date: date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'), dates))
```

Comment: I didn't realize that ArrayAgg was just returning a list of the datetime objects which were getting serialized by my view serializer.  I thought that the queryset was doing the serialization of the individual datetimes, hence my confusion.

Answer didn't necessarily match the question, but it pointed me to a hole in my understanding, so marking it as accepted. Thanks!